# How do I distribute a video as part of an introduction in a mobile app (iOS and hybrid)?

Tags: android, ios, video

I'm looking to add a video as part of an "intro" to a mobile app. I can't find any information online as it pertains to the development-specific portion of this.

How do you distribute the videos for different screen resolutions? Do you create multiple files, detect the screen density/size and deliver based on that? What's the industry standard?

Comment: How pixel-perfect does it need to be? Is it worth shipping a bunch of different-sized videos per-device, or can you just create a nice 1920x1080 and let the built-in video player on each device do its thing?

Comment: That's what I'm wondering. I want it to look as good as possible without compromising much quality.

Comment: Well, I think that's probably going to be an objective decision that you have to make. I don't know how well it would translate to a "hybrid" app, but iOS now supports app slicing and on-demand resources, that you can snag as you see fit: https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AppThinning/AppThinning.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH35-SW1

Comment: For comparison, we prepared a "tour" video for our app during the iPad1 days.  Here's the specs: 720x538 @ 30FPS and the file is 4.9MB.  This video is 1.44min long.  We opted to include the video in the app bundle that we dropped to Apple.

Comment: @LarryB, so just the one video file, then? Just let the app do the downsizing for the different devices?

Comment: From what I see you can, use "thinning" on images like icons.  Unfortunately, not videos.   http://artandlogic.com/2015/07/the-skinny-on-ios-app-thinning/   To allow people to download your app on cellular data, the app size needs to be smaller than 100MB.  If over 100MB, your users would have to be on wifi.  From the code you can determine the device the user is on and do something like if (idomiPad), then open a iPad optimal resolution video, else open iPhone video.  But, both videos will be on the device.  Apple now allows 4GB app size limits.